# How to defer execution of a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am implementing the classes in Python 2.7 as below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def do_something(self):
        """
        do something here
        """

class MyClassManager(object):
    def get_my_class_obj(self):
        """read my_class_obj from db"""
        return instance # instance has type MyClass


class MyClassUser(object):
    my_class_obj = new MyClass() # this is a class variable
```

In main:

```
MyClassUser.my_class_obj = MyClassManager().get_my_class_obj()
"""
do a lot of different things else in main
"""
```

From somewhere else:

```
"""only when some condition happens"""
MyClassUser.my_class_obj.do_something()
```

Is there a way I can defer the read obj (read from db inside `get_my_class_obj`) process in `MyClassManager` until `obj.do_something` method is actually invoked? Provided that I have to call `MyClassManager.get_my_class_obj` for some setup at the beginning. Suppose the situation is in the context of a web server and `do_something` will only be invoked when there is some request but I need to set up it first

Comment: Please clarify. What is a "read obj process"? Do you mean you have a file object and you're calling read() on it? Where are you doing that?

Comment: I mean the read obj from db inside **get_my_class_obj**

Comment: Why don't you call `get_my_class_obj` at the start of `do_something`? That is, inside the method itself?

Comment: Note: it is generally better to inherit classes from `object` when using Python 2.

Comment: It depends on your requirements really... I can see at least 5 different ways you can achieve that, but I can't recommend any without knowing what you actually want

Comment: What you're looking for is the "proxy" pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). There's no way to post an example implementation based only on your example snippet, but just looking up the term should get you started.

Comment: Can't you just make the `obj.do_something()` conditional. i.e. `if somecondition: obj.do_something()`?

Comment: Also note that writing an ORM (if that's what you're doing) is quite hard (if you expect it to work that is), you may want to look for existing ones (Peewee comes to mind: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)

Comment: @martineau: from what I understand, what the OP wants is to avoid loading the object (well, the object's state) from the database until it's really needed. I fail to see how "testing some condition" before calling the `do_something()` method would solve that.

Comment: @bruno: I think the question's unclear.

Comment: Yes, @brunodesthuilliers that is what I mean... Suppose the situation is in the context of a web server and `do_something` will only be invoked when there is some request. But I need to setup it first. I am looking at your recommendation. If I am being unclear, please tell

Comment: @Fred Could you give me some of the ideas? What information do you need to clarify the question? I think what I want is the same as the above comment of brunodesthuilliers.

Comment: @martineau well now the question is clear: the OP wants some kind of lazy loading so he doesn't hit the database until it's really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick&dirty, dumbed down possible solution (and certainly not how I'd design this but anyway). This example assume your object only has an id (db primary key) and a name (stored in db).

```
import functools

class MyClassManager(object):
    def get(self, object_id):
        return MyClass(object_id)

    def load(self, object):
        obj.name = self.get_from_db(object.id)

def autoload(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        self._load()
        return func(self, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper 

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self._name = name
        self._loaded = name is not None

    def _load(self):
        if self._loaded:
            return
        MyManager.load(self)

    @property
    @autoload
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @autoload
    def do_something(self):
        # your code here
```

But really, don't do this if you're a beginner (and you wouldn't ask if you were not), use an existing working ORM instead. Unless it's for educational purpose of course, in which case, well, you might either learn a lot or give up in despair - or both ;-)